# How to remove unwanted line breaks in html/css

Tags: html, css, templates

Working on a Django templates with a theme bought on themeforest. The problem I'm having is that, whenever I use base template, the header automatically adds line breaks to the top but when using hardcoded template files, it seems fine.[the white space at the top is an example of what im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90tRG.png) I'd be glad if anyone could help me on how to remove this unwanted space.

Here's the code of the header base template:

```html
{% load static %}

<div id="mainMenuBarAnchor"></div>
<header class="white_header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default bootsnav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="attr-nav">
            <div class="upper-column info-box first">
              <div class="icons"><i class="icon-telephone114"></i></div>
              <ul>
                <li><strong>Phone Number</strong></li>
                <li>+1 900 234 567 - 68</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index6.html"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" class="logo" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-in="fadeIn" data-out="fadeOut">
              <li class="dropdown active">
                <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home Style 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index2.html">Home Style 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index3.html">Home Style 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index4.html">Home Style 4</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="index5.html">Home Style 5</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="index6.html">Home Style 6</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="index7.html">Home Style 7</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="index8.html">Home Style 8</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="index9.html">Home Style 9</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="fullscreen.html">Home Fullscreen<span>new</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown megamenu-fw">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Listing</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu-content" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
                        <h5 class="title">PROPERTIES LIST</h5>
                        <div class="content">
                          <ul class="menu-col">
                            <li><a href="listing1.html">Properties List</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index7.html">Single Property</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing2.html">Search by City</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing5.html">Search by Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing3.html">Search by Type</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-menu col-md-9">
                        <h5 class="title bottom20">PROPERTIES LIST</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div id="nav_slider" class="owl-carousel">
                            <div class="item">
                              <div class="image bottom15"> 
                                <img src="{% static 'images/nav-slider1.jpg' %}" alt="Featured Property"> 
                                <span class="nav_tag yellow text-uppercase">for rent</span>
                              </div>
                              <h4><a href="property_detail1.html">Park Avenue Apartment</a></h4>
                              <p>Towson London, MR 21501</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                              <div class="image bottom15"> 
                                <img src="{% static 'images/nav-slider2.jpg' %}" alt="Featured Property"> 
                                <span class="nav_tag yellow text-uppercase">for rent</span>
                              </div>
                              <h4><a href="property_detail2.html">Park Avenue Apartment</a></h4>
                              <p>Towson London, MR 21501</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                              <div class="image bottom15"> 
                                <img src="{% static 'images/nav-slider3.jpg' %}" alt="Featured Property"> 
                                <span class="nav_tag yellow text-uppercase">for rent</span>
                              </div>
                              <h4><a href="property_detail3.html">Park Avenue Apartment</a></h4>
                              <p>Towson London, MR 21501</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                              <div class="image bottom15"> 
                                <img src="{% static 'images/nav-slider1.jpg' %}" alt="Featured Property"> 
                                <span class="nav_tag yellow text-uppercase">for rent</span>
                              </div>
                              <h4><a href="property_detail1.html">Park Avenue Apartment</a></h4>
                              <p>Towson London, MR 21501</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                              <div class="image bottom15"> 
                                <img src="{% static 'images/nav-slider2.jpg' %}" alt="Featured Property"> 
                                <span class="nav_tag yellow text-uppercase">for rent</span>
                              </div>
                              <h4><a href="property_detail2.html">Park Avenue Apartment</a></h4>
                              <p>Towson London, MR 21501</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                              <div class="image bottom15"> 
                                <img src="{% static 'images/nav-slider3.jpg' %}" alt="Featured Property"> 
                                <span class="nav_tag yellow text-uppercase">for rent</span>
                              </div>
                              <h4><a href="property_detail3.html">Park Avenue Apartment</a></h4>
                              <p>Towson London, MR 21501</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown megamenu-fw">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Properties</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu-content bg" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
                        <h5 class="title">PROPERTY LISTINGS</h5>
                        <div class="content">
                          <ul class="menu-col">
                            <li><a href="listing1.html">List Style 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing2.html">List Style 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing3.html">List Style 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing4.html">List Style 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing5.html">List Style 5</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
                        <h5 class="title">PROPERTY LISTINGS</h5>
                        <div class="content">
                          <ul class="menu-col">
                            <li><a href="listing6.html">List Style 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing7.html">List Style 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing1.html">Search by City</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing2.html">Search by Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing3.html">Search by Type</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
                        <h5 class="title">PROPERTY DETAIL</h5>
                        <div class="content">
                          <ul class="menu-col">
                            <li><a href="property_detail1.html">Property Detail 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="property_detail2.html">Property Detail 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="property_detail3.html">Property Detail 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index7.html">Single Property</a></li>
                            <li><a href="listing4.html">Search by Type</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
                        <h5 class="title">OTHER PAGES</h5>
                        <div class="content">
                          <ul class="menu-col">
                            <li><a href="favorite_properties.html">Favorite Properties</a></li>
                            <li><a href="agent_profile.html">Agent Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="testimonial.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Features </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">News</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="news.html">news Style1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="news2.html">news Style2<span>new</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="news3.html">news Style3<span>new</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Property Agents</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="agent1.html">Agent Style1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="agent2.html">Agent Style2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="agent3.html">Agent Style3<span>new</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="agent4.htm4">Agent Style4<span>new</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="agent5.htm5">Agent Style5<span>new</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Agetn Profile Styles</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="agent_profile.html">Agent Profile 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="agent_profile2.html">Agent Profile 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Testimonials</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="testimonial.html">Style 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="testimonial2.html">Style 2<span>new</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">FAQ's</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="faq.html">Style 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="faq2.html">Style 2<span>new</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="favorite_properties.html">Favorite Properties</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#." class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">404 Error</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="404.html">404 Error 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="404-2.html">404 Error 2<span>new</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#.">Buy Now</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code so that we have a [mcve], otherwise we're just taking guesses.

Comment: When you say "line breaks" are you referring to newlines in the source code (which shouldn't have any effect on the output), or `<br />` tags? Or are you referring to some kind of `margin-top` being set in the CSS? You need to show your code.

Comment: post your source code here

Comment: @4castle, yeah i meant kinda margin-top. I've got a few base templates and whenever I use them a page, let's say... {% include base1.html %} and {% include base2.html %}, at the top of base1 gonna be an unwanted margin and same goes for base2 as well. Hope the source code posted helps :(